# array method to check if index value between two arrays exists in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to compare 2 arrays and check if the value of 3 given indexes is common between the 2 arrays.
i.e.:

```
arr1 = [1,2,1,0,0,0,2,2,2]
arr2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2]
```

or

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,0,1,2,4,2,1]
arr2 = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
```

1st example here last 3 indexes are common.
2nd example here index 0,4,8 are common.

is there any method that can take the 2 arrays and return true if indexes are matching?

Comment: There is no inbuilt method. Create a javascript function that loos through the array and check value at each indices.

Comment: If you want to return true/false based on match result then, try like `const data = arr1.map((item, i) =>
  item > 0 && arr2[i] === item ? true : false
);`  Eg: https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/BawNvbX

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple

```js
const equal = (a1, a2, ...indexes) => indexes.every(i => a1[i] === a2[i]);
```

What i'm doing here is declaring a function that takes the first array as the first argument and the second array as the second parameters, now the third argument is basically grouping all the remaining parameters.

You would call this function like:

```js
equal([0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 6], 0, 3);
```

And this will return true

Comment: Please dont post answer for a question, where the user have not attempted anything.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,0,1,2,4,2,1]
const arr2 = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]

const indexes = arr1.reduce((accumulator, current, index) => {
  if (arr2[index] === current) {
    accumulator.push(index)
  }
  return accumulator
}, [])

console.log(indexes)

// Outputs : [0,3,4,8]
```

Comment: Please dont post answer for a question, where the user have not attempted anything.